# Build a query inside another with querybuilder?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, orm

I got 2 tables User and Group; each object Group got an array members[] that points to some instances of User.

I need to build this same query with QueryBuilder :

```
SELECT (users instances) FROM User
WHERE (users instances) IN (SELECT Group.members from Group WHERE group.id = $someId)
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make 2 querybuilders:

```
$qb2 = $this->em->createQueryBuilder('group')
            ->select('group.members')
            ->where('group.id = $someId');

$qb = $this->em->createQueryBuilder('user')
           ->select(user instances)
           -where($qb->expr()->in('user instances', $qb2->getDQL());
```

it will give you the idea how it works. Of course you have to adjust this code to yours.

Comment: Right. I would add the setParameter option instead of passing $someId directly. Well done! Regards

Comment: Of course set parameter is good practice, I just wanted to show a much as possible same query as he showed.

Comment: Thank you but I got this "Undefined property: Project\UserBundle\Repository\UserRepository::$em" error. Do you know how to correct it?

Comment: Try $em = $this->getEntityManager();

Comment: Thanks it worked but now I got this error "Undefined variable: qb" at this line : `->where($qb->expr()->in('user', $qb2->getDQL()))`

Comment: Sure. It happens because you are calling $qb before it is totally defined. You could use  i.e $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder('user'); $query = $qb->select(user instances)
           -where($qb->expr()->in('user instances', $qb2->getDQL());

Comment: I got one last error I think : `Expected end of string, got '('`

Comment: And this is the query that is made, it seems correct to me so I don't know where is the error : `SELECT Project\UserBundle\Entity\User WHERE Project\UserBundle\Entity\User IN(SELECT UserGroup.members WHERE UserGroup.school = :school AND UserGroup.name = "Teacher")`

Comment: please post your query :)

Answer (score 1):

Improving @Eimsas Answer it could be:

```
$em = $this->getEntityManager();

$qb2 = $em->createQueryBuilder('group')
            ->select('group.members')
            ->where('group.id = $someId');

$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder('user');
$query = $qb->select(user instances)
            ->where($qb->expr()->in('user instances', $qb2->getDQL());
$result = $query->getQuery->getResult();
```